# Is this a bad tile/grout job?

Tags: bathroom, tile, grout

https://imgur.com/a/JuHDN5y

Hi! Looking for some help bc I'm not quite sure about the tile job that was just completed.

Before getting started/buying everything, I had showed the tilers a picture of the vertical grid tile we wanted in order to see if it would be possible bc we read that it was a more finicky design. I really liked the look of the stacked subway tiles (I know it's not everyone's cup of tea), but was considering using a larger format tile in case it was easier for them to install. They said the stacked 4x12 would take some time to complete but that it wouldn't be a problem at all.

About a week later— they finished grouting today, and something feels/looks a bit off to my untrained eye. Some general thoughts/observations:

- I don't know why they didn't tile all the way up to the edge of the ceiling like I had initially asked.
- The shower floor edge looks quite odd and uneven. There were 4 more sheets of tile, but it looks unfinished as if they had run out of tile to finish going all the way down the edge.
- There are some spots where the tile is a bit bumpy/not on a level plane.
- The tile directly above the window looks a little slanted.
- Some of the grout lines seem uneven. (They used Spectralock 1.)
- Some of the tile grid pattern looks uneven/not straight.
- The niche looks a bit crooked/slanted.

I was wondering if folks could weigh in bc I'm not entirely sure if this is just normal/fine. If things aren't very good, what are possible solutions and next steps? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you should have checked their progress before they grouted.  It seems to me that they are saving you money by not tiling to the roof/ceiling, as there is a tiny bit left on the level and then it slopes.  Other imperfections could be because the walls and niche themselves were out and/or the tiles are not square or level... this happens with some imported tiles.

Comment: What I am getting at is that you havent specified those things, so we can't judge.

Comment: Hard to tell from a photo with perspective and all.  If you can put a straight edge on the grout lines and demonstrate that they are crooked, you may have a case.  As far as the floor, you need it to slope to the drain, which it looks like it does.  Also, note that many tiles are not necessarily flat, individually.  They may look that way, but if you put a straight edge on them you'll see.  Finally, it looks like you need some caulk along the corner of the curb and floor.

Comment: Were the walls perfectly flat drywall, or something else not entirely flat? Who built the shower tub? The tile guy or someone else?

Comment: please do not post a link to pictures ... use the button with the moon and mountains to add the pictures directly into the question

Comment: It's hard to tell from the pics if the shower tub is square and floor tile is laid at an angle, or if the tub was crooked and the tile guy did what he could. OP can you put a square (I mean the tool, preferably a big one, to avoid errors from tile thickness variation) in all 4 angles of the tub and report your findings?

Comment: Not a stellar job in my opinion. Tile is a craft. Not sure what you’d do to fix it, except I’d suggest you paint out the grout at the ceiling.